Unable to access Storage Account using User assigned Identity
I am trying to access a Storage account using Create Blob(V2) logic app action using User assigned identity but encountering the following error:

The logic app and storage account is in the same resource group and I have also added the necessary role Storage Blob Data Contributor to the user assigned identity in the storage account.
Plan Type
Consumption
Steps to Reproduce the Bug or Issue

Create a User assigned identity
Create Logic app action Create Blob (V2) , add the required storage account details and in the managed identity section select the user assigned identity
Go to the storage account and add the role Storage Blob Data Contributor to the user managed identity
Run the workflow


I have followed below steps to establish a connection to storage account from logic app using user managed identity-

Three of my resources (consumption logic app, user managed identity, v2 storage account) are in same location and in same resource group.
I enabled user managed identity in logic app as shown below.




Added Storage Blob Data Contributor RBAC role to User managed identity instance in storage account.



Created Create Blob (V2) action as below-



Got it worked successfully.



What are the networking settings for your storage account? @Ikhtesam If I make the storage account publicly accessible then it is working fine.

@Geetika Its Enabled from all network in storage account

@Geetika what is your network setting? is it disabled?

Yes the setting is "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses" with Exceptions set to "Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account." and have also added "Microsoft.Logic/workflows" in Resource Instances

@Geetika Yes, you need to create both logic app and storage account in different region and try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78388391/azure-logic-connection-with-azure-file-share-while-storage-account-is-behind-fir/78389434#78389434

I can access the storage account using system assigned identity, it's just the user managed identity that is causing the error. Do I still need to follow the different region approach?

Yes, If you would like to use the user managed identity then you can go for the different region approach as adding exception resource in storage account is only works for system managed identity. SO you need to add the region IPs in the firewall. If you are okay for using system managed identity then you can skip it
